# Find rows with like in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a procedure that would find a record with the matched LIKE keyword, this is what i've got:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure proc_search_tracks_name(q IN tracks.track_name%TYPE)
AS
results tracks%rowtype;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO results FROM tracks WHERE track_name LIKE '%' + q + '%';
  dbms_output.put_line(results.track_id || ' ' || results.track_name);
END proc_search_tracks_name;

/
declare
Begin
 proc_search_tracks_name('Love');
end;
/
```

But for some reason i get the ORA-01722: invalid number error, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using SQL Server syntax for concatenating strings.  Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO results FROM tracks WHERE track_name LIKE '%' || q || '%';
```

If you have multiple rows, then you have a problem with `into`.  You can limit it to one row. 
I think this will work

```
SELECT * INTO results FROM tracks WHERE track_name LIKE '%' || q || '%' WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Comment: tried this, number error has disappeared, thanks =) however, now there is a ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows error?

Comment: The condition works, utilizing the "select into" approach is designed for situations where you obtain 1 record back.  It looks like you need a declared cursor approach.

Comment: What if i were to retrieve all of the rows, cant i do something like    for i in 1..results loop
 dbms_output.put_line(results.track_name(i));
 end loop; except oracle doesn't like this either

Comment: thank you i read about explicit cursors and made it finally work, thank you so much for you help =)